# Why is nav bar sliding down skinny and then widening?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When you hover over a nav li item on my website, it should slide down the nav ul ul item, but when it slides down for some reason it is skinny, then widens after. Please look at my JSFiddle and help me out :D

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fnjg566p/1/)

HTML:

```
    <body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="about.html">About Me</a></li>
                </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="purpose.html">Purposeful Living</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="purpose78.html">7th - 8th</a></li>
                    <li><a href="purpose910.html">9th - 10th</a></li>
                    <li><a href="purpose1112.html">11th - 12th</a></li>
                </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="academic.html">Academic Excellence</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="purpose78.html">7th - 8th</a></li>
                    <li><a href="purpose910.html">9th - 10th</a></li>
                    <li><a href="purpose1112.html">11th - 12th</a></li>
                </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="ethical.html">Ethical Responsibility</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="purpose78.html">7th - 8th</a></li>
                    <li><a href="purpose910.html">9th - 10th</a></li>
                    <li><a href="purpose1112.html">11th - 12th</a></li>
                </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div id="headershow">Toggle Nav Bar</div>
    <div id="mainnamesection">
        <h1 id="mainname">
        Title
        </h1>
        <div id="flyingsection">
    </div>
        <h1 id="mainname1">
        <span id="smallname">Subtitle</span>
        </h1>
    </div>
</body>
```

Javascript/Jquery:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {



$("#smallname").click(function() {

$("html, body").animate({scrollTop: "0px"});

});         

$("#headershow").click(function() {

$("header").slideToggle();

});

$(".grades td a").mouseover(function() {
$(this).animate({backgroundColor: "white", color: "black"}, 200);
$(this).mouseleave(function() {
$(this).animate({backgroundColor: "transparent", color: "white"}, 200);
});
});

$('nav li').hover(
function () {
$('ul', this).slideDown();
},
function () {
$('ul', this).stop().slideUp();
}
);          

});
```

CSS:

```
`    @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);



    body {
    background-image: url(file:///Users/jakesager/Desktop/Websites/Jake%20Sager/img/starrynight.jpg);
    background-size: 110%;
    background-position: center -100px;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    margin:auto;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
    height: 60px;
    z-index: 20;
    display: none;
}

.inline {
    display: inline-block;
}

#flyingbird {
    height: 60px;
    width: 90px;
    left: 100px;
    position: relative;
    top: -30px;
}

#bird {
    height: 60px;
    width: 90px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: 15px;
    z-index: 1;
}

#flyingsection {
    width: 700px;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

nav {
    height: 60px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 20;
}

nav ul ul {
    display:none;
}

#headershow {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
    position: static;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 125px;
    text-align:center;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: open sans;
}

nav ul {
    list-style:none;
    display: inline-table;
    position:relative;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: open sans;
    display: inline-block;
}

nav ul li {
    float: left;
    margin-top: -16px;
    border-right: 2px solid black;
    text-align:center;
    height: 60px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
}

nav ul li:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}

nav ul li a {
    color:black;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    position: relative;
    top: 18px;
}

nav ul li:first-child {
    border-left: 2px solid black;
}

nav ul li:last-child {
    border-right: 2px solid black;
}

nav ul li:hover {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.6)
}
nav ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    z-index: 20;
}

nav ul ul li {
    float:none;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.82);
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: -27px;
    border-left: 2px solid black;
    border-right: 2px solid black;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}
nav ul ul li:last-child {
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

nav ul ul li:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
}

#mainnamesection {
    width: 1050px;
    margin:auto;
}
#mainname {
    font-size: 180px;
    font-family: open sans;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top: 20px;
    color: white;
}
#mainname1 {
    font-size: 180px;
    font-family: open sans;
    text-align:center;
    color: white;
    margin-top: -100px;
}
#smallname {
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: open sans;
    color: #47BCEA;
}

nav ul ul {
    margin-left: 0;
}

.maincontent {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding-top: 7px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    color: white;
}

.maincontent p {
    font-family: open sans;
    margin-left: 20px;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.maincontent h1 {
    font-family: open sans;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.grades {
    margin-left: 20px;
    background-color: rgba(000,000,000, 0.7);
    font-family: open sans;
    font-size: 23px;
}

.grades td {
    padding: 10px;
    border-right: 2px solid white;
}

.grades td:last-child {
    border: none;
}

.grades td a {
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 941px;
    margin:auto;
}
.maintitle {
    font-family: Open sans;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.mainparagraph {
    font-family: Open sans;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

During the animation `overflow` is set to `hidden`. When animation completes the inline `overflow` style is removed.

You have negative margin set on sub menu `<li>` so while the animation is in progress the part that is outside the parent is not visible.

Suggest you remove the negative margin and set the `<ul>` to `left:0`

Comment: That only half salved the problem, literally... Now the left side is coming down like normal but the right side expands after animation is complete...

Comment: same issue with margins